# JavaScript calculator not updating values

Tags: javascript, html

I have a problem with my JavaScript calculator. Whenever I want to add, for example, 5+5, the result stays at 10 (blocked on one value) and does not add to the previous result (10, 15, 20, etc.).

Here is my code:

```js
function add() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a + b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = +c;
}

function sub() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a - b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = +c;
}

function mult() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a * b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = +c;
}

function div() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a / b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = +c;
}

function divmod() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a % b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = +c;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  <input type="text" id="l1" />
  <input type="text" id="l2" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="sub()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="mult()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="%" onclick="divmod()" />
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="div()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="clean" class="class2" />
  <br/>
  <p style="color:white; font-size:30px;">Result:</p>
  <input type="text" id="result" />
  <br/>
</form>
```

Where is the problem? I tried add `+` before `=` in `document.getElementById('result').value = +c` but it did not update the value then, but added `5 + 5` as `55`.

Comment: @JaromandaX No it doesn't, it replaces the existing value instead of adding to it. Please don't post answers in the comments section, particularly wrong ones.

Comment: @JaromandaX Read the problem they asked, "stays at 10 (blocked on one value) and does not add to the previous result (10, 15, 20, etc.)." They want to add to the result the value, not replace the result with the value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add to the number by first parsing the value to an int:

```js
document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
```

With just a `= newValue`, that is changing the value of result to be the `c` variable .
With just a `+= newValue`, that is concatenation since document.thing.value will always return a string, and a string + number promotes the number to a string. 
So you need to say `oldStringValue = parseInt(oldStringValue) + newNumberValue;`

The value of result also needs to be initialized to 0, either through the HTML or JavaScript, otherwise parseInt() will return NaN. I chose to do it in the JavaScript, as that's more clear.

```js
document.getElementById('result').value = 0;

function add() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a + b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
}

function sub() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a - b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
}

function mult() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a * b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
}

function div() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a / b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
}

function divmod() {
  var a = parseInt(document.getElementById('l1').value);
  var b = parseInt(document.getElementById('l2').value);
  var c = parseInt(a % b);
  document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;
}
```

```html
<form name="calculator">
  <input type="text" id="l1" />
  <input type="text" id="l2" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="+" onclick="add()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="-" onclick="sub()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" onclick="mult()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="%" onclick="divmod()" />
  <input type="button" value="/" onclick="div()" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" value="clean" class="class2" />
  <br/>
  <p style="color:white; font-size:30px;">Result:</p>
  <input type="text" id="result" />
  <br/>
</form>
```

Comment: That's better ;)

Comment: Hmmm, something strange - it keeps returning NaN

Comment: @JimPanse that's because the initial value of document.getElementById('result').value is an empty string, so just set it to "0' at the beginning like i did in the snippet

Comment: @Samathingamajig Thank you! Now it works perfectly fine

Comment: @Samathingamajig one more question. Shouldn't it be oldStringValue = parseInt(oldStringValue) - newNumberValue; in function sub() and oldStringValue = parseInt(oldStringValue) * newNumberValue; in function mult() etc.? Or should it stay as +?

Comment: @JimPanse If I am understanding your total objective correctly, then it should all stay as `old + new`

Answer (score 3):

While the `+c` is on the right track (converting c to a number), c is already a number, it is the result of parseInt(). The reason you got 55 is because it was concatenating strings, not adding numbers (JS can be funky with the string to number thing because it is not a strongly typed language). Javascript's type coercion can be a big pain sometimes!

I believe that getting the value of result, casting it to an integer, adding `c` to that integer, and THEN setting the DOM element value will get you the behavior you are looking for.

I am being intentionally vague because I believe you have demonstrated that you have the knowledge and tools to do this from your code sampling above. If you still can't get it to work after more effort, please comment on this answer and I will provide a more in depth solution.

Comment: It's valid syntax. It's just not what they wanted.

Comment: Does `= +` do the same thing as `+=`? I've never seen `= +` anywhere before.

Comment: It's not `= +` as much as it is `+c`. Read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Unary_plus#:~:text=The%20unary%20plus%20operator%20(%20%2B%20),if%20it%20isn't%20already.).

Comment: Ah cool, I hate it. Thanks for making me aware of that construction. Are there any benefits to using `+{var}` over parseInt/float? I think what it makes up for in brevity is lost in clarity.

Comment: It's always going to be a matter of opinion, but I'd tend to agree with you here, and my gut feel is that most other programmers would too.

Comment: @AdamSpecker strange. I changed "document.getElementById('result').value = +c;" to "document.getElementById('result').value = parseInt(document.getElementById('result').value) + c;" as Samathingamajig said but it keeps returning NaN.

Comment: Great! Happy to help. Now that you understand WHAT to do, do you understand WHY it happened? This type of issue will most definitely crop up again in your development growth.